# Разное отображение slike на chrome и safari

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, bootstrap, slick.js

Целый день не могу понять в чем проблема!!! Недавно запустил сайт на wordpress https://xn--80ateidbei.xn--90ais/ все работало отлично, на всякий случай сделал бэкап(сейчас он не устраняет ошибку). ПРОБЛЕМА в следующем: В safari все отражается отлично, в хроме некорректно.
Вот так отображается в safari как и должно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как отображается в chrome:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот какие ошибки выдает chrome:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошлый бэкап не помог(работало все идеально. Кто сталкивался подскажите что делать?

Comment: Слайдер в хроме отображается как надо. Но ошибки сыпет)

Comment: А почему раньше отображался по другому? И в сафари ошибок нет, и отображается как раньше в хроме